# Querying database in a loop, loop with a sleep, or separate request

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, performance

I'm considering the 3 options and ill take more suggestions if any come up.

**The problem**: I keep getting advised to ditch the sleep and I don't have the background to pick between the three

I keep getting told that sleep is very bad to use in a php script but no one ever highlights why. I intend for the system to be scalable ie the solution to this problem could be used 10 to 100 fold.

Option 1: sleep

```
$timer = time() + (30);

while($done==0){
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
  $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if ($row_cnt>0){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    print $row[0];
    $done=1;}

  else{
    $current = time();
    if( $timer>$current){sleep(1);}
    else{$done=1;}
  }
```

Option 2:

Simply remove the sleep from above my non sever knowledge thinks this is worse but, I'm sure I could be very wrong

```
else{
  $current = time();
  if(   $timer>$current){}
  else{$done=1;}
}
```

Option 3: is to have the client ask for the page in a loop and have the file simply present the info

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($row_cnt>0){
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  print $row[0];
```

So which is best given 
My goals:

- reliability-Most importance
- speed which client gets info
- scalability - lowest importance(still important)

Please give me a why I really want to understand a claim that one method is superior

If this gets marked as debatable it must mean all answers are valid :) and I'll take that as an answer :)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: the problem is i keep getting advised to ditch the sleep and I dont have the background to pick between the three

Comment: Why do you have the sleep in the first place? It was presumably put there to solve some problem, since it's not normal in database query scripts.

Comment: @Barmar im continuously querying the database to send the client back data... quick to me is within a few seconds so i thought i would add it to reduce stress on the database ...

Comment: while not directly related to this question, a lot of readers should learn from the "keep getting told" with "but no one ever highlights why"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using PHP's sleep, if you understand that PHP is single threaded and it will pause execution of the rest of the script.

This is definitely not the "Right Thing" to do. What will happen when you start connecting more clients is that you will have many apache PHP threads which will all be sleeping waiting for the same event. You will run out of resources very quickly. What you are doing is essentially long polling. sleep or no sleep, its still bad.

One of the better approaches would be to make this system more event based. When an event comes in, the data gets pushed out to all the clients. Dependent on what technology you have available to you this will be very flexible and will only incur the network latency. Something like WebSockets fits very well here.

Since you are on a µC and can't do websockets easily, best thing to do would be to open a persistent TCP connection to the server, and just send data down it.

The next best thing would be to make the script execute fast, by caching results, say in [memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached). Memcached is essentially an in memory key value store. You would use your clientId or something that identifies a client uniquely as the key. The process would be something like this:

Results data is updated from some external source and is added to the database. If the data is per client in nature then delete (invalidate) that client's key in memcache so when it requests the results it is forced to go directly to the database. If the results aren't per client when you record them, run through all the clients currently connected and invalidate their caches individually. This process will be fast as everything is in RAM.

When the clients request results, the script should look first in memcache using the clientID as the key, if it isn't found query the database and put the result into memcache for later.

I don't have any good memcache tutorials on hand, but a quick google search turned up this one, which doesn't suck: http://www.stevenmcmillan.co.uk/blog/2010/php5-memcached-example/

I would also advise you to reconsider using raw TCP sockets. You are really missing out, as you can make a realtime connection between your clients and the server, and your code overall can be simpler. If your hosting doesn't allow it, get a better hosting provider. There are so many cheap ones, if you can't afford ~$5 a month, I worry about your nutrition. Two that I have atm are RamNode and DigitalOcean.

Other than that you really need to describe your situation in a bit more detail.

Comment: your spot on...I cant use sockets at all in my situation which I know would be superior here. Can you elaborate on one thing for me "cache the db result heavily and make sure that the whole script returns as fast as possible" ...What exactly do you mean?

Comment: If you have 100s of clients polling for this script, each at 1 second intervals you must do as much as you can to make sure that script doesn't take more than a few milliseconds to run. In this situation outstanding requests will pile up very fast

Comment: Yes i get this I mean on what it means cache the database result heavily ?

Comment: If the database result is the same for every client put it into memcache, so you don't hit the database. Invalidate the cache when new data comes in. (It doesn't have to be memcache, but it is really fast)

Comment: I can also see that your clients are µCs, You should definitely open a persistent TCP socket instead of doing HTTP requests.

Comment: every client will have different results but the length of time the results stay the same could be hours ... do you have any suggested readings on such topic

Comment: Cant do sockets :( my current sever has socket listening disallowed

Comment: If the results themselves aren't big, you can cache them per client basis. If the results are big, just cache a boolean wether there are results or not. Why can't you listen on a socket? Work/Ops requirement or a hosting restriction?

Comment: hosting disallows the listening and I could switch the client to a server but this would mean setting up port forwarding on the client side which is also not an option...So im left with this method

Comment: The results are tiny a string of max: 50 characters...I have no idea about the cache per client basis .... how would that even work ...? Sorry im a complete noob to what your suggesting... can you elaborate or suggest what to google search ?

Comment: Get better hosting. I'll edit my answer, this is getting long

Comment: Haha .. would you be surprised if I said that's also not an option...Thanks for your help I really appreciate it !

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge i really appreciate it... I look forward to your edited answer

Comment: Do you still plan on updating your answer

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at why programmers consider `sleep` bad in a loop, which seems to be the heart of your question.

Short answer, yes you can use sleep.

Why would you *not* then?

What you *ideally* want is to do some work when data becomes available in your database. For this, if you can get notified when data becomes available then you've done the least amount of work. There are multiple way to achieve this in programming: webhooks in the HTTP world, locks / semaphores, callbacks, and events / observers are a few paradigms. Another cited reason is [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), which I will let you read about. Since the database is doing things atomically for you, this is not so much of a worry.

However, in the *ideal* stateless world that is HTTP, you can't lock, and sometimes you simply can't get events or callbacks. I've seen some AJAX programming encourage the use of polling at fixed or random intervals, which is essentially a form of sleep as far as the server is concerned.

Your option 2 is the worst as your program is doing LOTS of useless work. All that useless work is costing you electricity and hogging resources (CPU) that could go elsewhere. If you login to the computer, run any other programs, serve websites, all of these will be slower.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. So if you had to say would 3 or 1 be better?

Comment: 3 or 1 look fine - although I don't really know the full picture

Comment: 100 people connected to the server and in a loop with a sleep is ~= to 100 people connecting to the server over and over again... Im curious as to why the whole picture matters ...What is the data your missing to make a conclusion